# Why do I have to put fillcolor setting inside preview environment?

Tags: pstricks, preview, standalone

It seems to me this problem related to PSTricks so I have to modify the previous question.

`\psset{fillstyle=solid,linecolor=red}` that I define globally outside the `preview` environment can affect the graphics object. But why do I have to put `\psset{fillcolor=green}` inside the `preview` environment to make it works?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{fillstyle=solid,linecolor=red}

% the following setting will be ignored by preview
% \psset{fillcolor=green}

\begin{document}
\preview
% Thus the setting must be inside the preview, does it seem strange to you?
\psset{fillcolor=green}
\psframebox{Karl's students}
\endpreview
\end{document}
```

Is `fillcolor` very special  in this case?

Comment: I think that's how preview works. Only the stuff between the `preview` environment gets executed after `\begin{document}`. Otherwise use `crop` option instead of `preview` in the class options.

Comment: @percusse: See my update because I just found that it is heavily related to `fillcolor` option.

Comment: It's not related to `\preview`.  The issue comes up whether you use `preview` or not.  It seems to have to do with where you call `\psset`.  Setting things in the preamble doesn't always have the desired effect.  Not sure why at this point.  If you place your `\psset{fillcolor=green}` immediately after `begin{document}` it will work, but not if you place it inside the preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look inside `pstricks.sty`, at the very end of the package you will find the following line:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \psset{fillcolor=white}%      hv 0.33
  \let\pst@endcolor=\relax%
%  \let\pst@color=\relax%
% LaTeX used `\color@endgroup' instead. RN 2004-05-06
}
```

Thus trying to set `fillcolor` inside the preamble will be defeated once you hit `\begin{documnent}`

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\AtBeginDocument{\psset{fillstyle=solid,linecolor=red}}
```

Comment: But what is the purpose of setting `fillcolor=white` at the begin document in `pstricks.sty`?

Comment: Problems when there is no defined fillcolor

Comment: Why wasn't it put at the bottom of `pstrick.sty` but not inside `\AtBeginDocument` (because our global `\psset{}` is always below `\usepackage{pstricks}`)?

Comment: because no one should set it to undefined

Comment: I meant `\psset{fillcolor=white}` should be defined at the bottom of `pstricks.sty` but not inside `\AtBeginDocument{}`. So this setting can be overridden by us via `\psset{fillcolor=<other color>}` that we put below `\usepackage{pstricks}`.

Comment: I am still confused with the fact other keys can have default values but why cannot `fillcolor` have a default value as well at the point it is declared?

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument` allows to define something which cannot be overwritten by other packages which are loaded _after_ pstricks

Comment: Other keys defined in PSTricks might have default values when they are declared/defined at the first time. Why weren't they all put inside `\AtBeginDocument` to prevent users overriding  them? What makes `fillcolor` very special in this case? I also believe, there will be no pacakges loaded after `pstricks` trying to set the PSTricks keys to undefined.

Comment: I think `fillcolor` will never be undefined because `\define@key[psset]{pstricks}{fillcolor}[white]{\pst@getcolor{#1}\psfillcolor}
\psset[pstricks]{fillcolor=white}`.

Answer (score 0):

This weird feature has been disabled in the current `pstricks.sty`.

Comment: @texenthusiast: No. It has not been mentioned in the news letter yet.